# Unwanted overlap inserting UI objects in a RichTextBlock using InlineUIContainer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a C# Metro application.
In the XAML code of my page I have a RichTextBlock  that I'm filling this way:

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding ContentBefore}"/>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Button Content="TEST" Width="300" Height="150"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding ContentAfter}"/>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

What I'd like to see is the ContentBefore text followed by a button and followed by the ContentAfter text.

Instead, the button (or whatever other element I try to put there, a Grid filled with stuff, for instance) overlaps both ContentBefore and ContentAfter.
The only way I manage to obtain space for the button is by inserting some LineBreaks to "make space", which obviously isn't an acceptable solution.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem, maybe you can use `<Paragraph LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">` to resolve this.